Relating attachments table with a new GlobalID in ArcGIS Pro
I am not familiar with ArcGIS at all, I come from a simple QGIS background. I do not code.
I have data that was collected in Survey123 using a device that did not have geolocation enabled. Instead, surveyors entered UTM coordinates manually. This layer's points all show up at 0,0 (middle of the ocean). This survey contains a table of photo attachments that are linked to specific points.
Here is what I have tried to far:

I used the tool "XY Table to Points" and converted the old survey File Geodatabase Feature Class to a new File Geodatabase Feature Class that uses the UTM coordinates to project. That's great, it is showing up correctly now. However, that broke the link to the attachments table.

I tried to use the Environment setting "Preserve GlobalID" when creating the XY Table to Points, but it still created new GlobalIDs anyway.

I tried to find tools that changed the spatial reference settings of the original Feature Class set, but could not find a way to use fields in the data set to determine where the points go. There are two fields, UTME and UTMN, that contain the values. This is really simple in QGIS, you just tell QGIS where the data for coordinates is located, but Arc does not seem to play that way.


I need a solution that both:

makes the layer's spatial data accurate (use the UTM coordinate fields rather than the default 0,0 coordinates)
links back up to the correct photos in the attachments table


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. I suggest you [Edit] the Question to focus on how to preserve the GlobalID value during conversion, instead of recovering after it has been lost.

@Vince Yes, that is another route I have looked at. I turned on the Environment parameter "Preserve GlobalID" for the survey gdb I am working in, but when I used XY to Table, it still created new GlobalIDs anyway. If there's a better way to tell Arc to stop trying to project the values at 0,0 in the ocean and use the UTM coordinates that doesn't require creating a new table that would be ideal, but I spent an entire day looking for solutions to that, to no avail. I'm open to any sort of work around that uses the right spatial data source and links back up to the table.

I don't have the ArcGIS vocabulary to describe my problem better than this, sorry.

GlobalID fields are supposed to be unique. What you want is a UUID type field. It still comes down to editing the Question to contain these details.
